# Renaming title field in Sharepoint list creates another title field

Tags: list

Whenever I am trying to rename the title field in Sharepoint list, instead of renaming the field it creates another field with display name Title and Internal name as Title1. Here is my code:

```
SPList splist = spWeb.Lists["listName"];
spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
var field = splist.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title];
field.Title = "Last Name";
field.Update();
spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Field's DisplayName in a List](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34144/change-fields-displayname-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

For SP2010/07, the internal name of Title cannot be modified, yet you can change displayname for Title.

use field.DisplayName = "Last Name"

Here, the internal name is Title and display name is "Last Name".

Comment: DisplayName property does not exists. To change the display name field.Title is used

Comment: Since field is of type var, DisplayName cannot exists, it should be SPlistitem